# what's the difference between the two statements... context.getImageData().data and

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

```
var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var data = imageData.data;
```

and

```
var data = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
```

they both have different effect, why?

Comment: they do?  What is the different effect?

Comment: @Fosco view-source:http://jakearchibald.com/scratch/alphavid/ - line 49 and 50, if you change the way I asked in question, you'll see the effect... its not transparent anymore

Comment: to make the code work correctly you must change more that just lines 49 and 50 - that code needs both variables in later lines and your version only declares one of them.

Comment: @Alnitak I didn't replace the two lines with just one. I replaced "var data = imageData.data;" with "var data = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;" so the "var imageData" remains intact.

Comment: please show the actual non-working code - your variable names don't match the original source so I still can't tell what you've done.

Comment: @Alnitak http://jakearchibald.com/scratch/alphavid/ <- this is the actual code, you'll have to download the video files hosted >> http://jakearchibald.com/scratch/alphavid/compressed.mp4 and http://jakearchibald.com/scratch/alphavid/compressed.ogv

Comment: no, I mean the version without working transparency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've changed the code per your comments, i.e. you now have:

```
var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var data = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
```

then your problem is *probably* that you've now got two separate copies of the image's pixel data, and the one you're modifying isn't then the one that's copied back.

Comment: so, you're saying that in case#1 any changes to the "var data" will be reflected back to the "var imageData" but not in case#2 ? I though you'd have separate copies anyways. I can't find documentation for .data anywhere...

Comment: the value returned by `.getImageData()` contains several properties, _one_ of which is `.data` - an _array like_ structure of RGBA values.  In the original case the code obtains a _reference_ to that structure, not a new copy, so changes to `data` _do_ affect `imageData`.

Comment: whereas in your code (as far as I can tell) you've really made two separate copies of the image data.